# How to make a browser display an anchor using Vert.x web

Tags: java, html, vert.x

I need to access a page that contains anchors using vert.x web.

I have a page (for example: a page called display.html) that has some anchors in it. I am using the vert.x web API to display this page.

Using the routers, I am able to get at this page, in the following manner:

```
  router.route("/display.html").blockingHandler(rctx->{
     HttpServerResponse resp = rctx.response();
     resp.putHeader("content-type","text/html");
     resp.setChunked(true);

     String content = getFile("./webpage/display.html");
     resp.write(content);
     resp.end();
  },false);
```

This allows me to access the page from the browser using the following request:

http://localhost:8080/display.html

My problem is that I cannot figure out a way to make the browser go to the anchors on the page. For example, I need to do the equivilant of the following:

http://localhost:8080/display.html#xl_xr_page_-a

I can find no way to make the server pass such a thing to the browser.

Is there a way to make a Vert.x server do this? How does a server like Tomcat or even Apache manage to handle this -- especially when a browser doesn't send anchor tags to the server. The tags are in the web page, so there must be some way of getting the browser to display them. If so, how can this be done?

Someone please advise...

Comment: You might want to redirect the browser to a URL containing your `#values`...

Comment: This does not solve the problem. Apparently, the browser still doesn't process the anchor even if it is explicitly specified, whether it is in a redirect or a direct request...

Comment: This has nothing to do with the server. It is the browser's responsibility to navigate to the anchor. In HTML5 no `<a>` tags needed, `#apple` would navigate to the element whose ID is `apple`...